# Detectar si una variable incrementa o disminuye un numero determinado

Tags: swift, swift4

Poseo una variable que cambia de valor del 1 al 360 , me gustaría saber como detectar si el valor aumenta o disminuye 45 e imprimirlo.
Este es mi código hasta ahora

```
              let x = location.course 
              let y = x ;

              
              if (x > y) {
             //la idea es descubrir si aumentó 45
                  print("Aumentó 45 \(x)");
              } else {
            //la idea es descubrir si disminuyó 45
                  print("Disminuyó 45 \(x)");
              }
```

Comment: Desde donde cambias el valor de `course`, llama a una función con el código que tienes.

Comment: Podrías explicarlo más detalladamente? no lo eh entendido, tengo poca experiencia en swift.

Comment: Agrega el código en una función y que reciba como parámetro `location.course`. En la función en donde obtienes el valor de `location.course` llama a la nueva función que creaste `miNuevaFuncion(location.course)`.